# Python - Binary search to find elements of a list that match the index?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, binary-search

So I want to search a list using binary search, and find elements of the list that have a value that matches the index number. For example, if my list contains a 2 at index 2, I want to print that value. It has to work with multiple values as well. Here is what I have so far for a binary search:

```
alist=[4,5,7,9,13,45,34,58,99,125,145]
key=145
"""Search key in alist[start... end - 1]."""
start = 0
end = len(alist)
while start < end:
    mid = (start + end)//2
    if alist[mid] > key:  # this is where we check if the guess is bigger than the key
            end = mid
    elif alist[mid] < key:
            start = mid + 1
    elif alist[mid] == key:
                print (f"you searched for {alist[mid]} and we found it in the index number {alist.index(125)} of the list")
                break
else:
    print ("Not Found!")
```

This will only work with a key. I'm new to python and wondering how I would go about implementing this.

Comment: Why do you want to use binary search for this? Sounds more like you want to traverse the list and check every element individually.

Comment: But it looks like the list is sorted, so the complexity can be reduced through binary search @a_guest

Comment: @yatu I don't think binary search will help. First of all the list isn't sorted. Even if it was the OP doesn't want to locate a single element but an arbitrary number elements that satisfy some condition based on their position in the list.

Comment: Yes if the list isn't sorted indeed binary search won't make sense, I though it was but just noticed those 2 elements that aren't. Bu if they were sorted, you could easily discard big sections of the list if you see that the value has already surpassed the index, say, you'd have no need to traverse one of the sides any more @a_guest

Comment: @yatu I don't think that's true. If the list is sorted (and contains only positive values) then you'd need to allow duplicates so that the problem makes sense (otherwise it's trivial, start from the beginning until the first element infringes the condition). Then there are three options: `a = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]; b = [0, 1, 1, 3, 4]; c = [0, 1, 3, 3, 4]`. Binary search starts in the middle, at index 2. The three lists are only different in that element. They represent all possible cases, i.e. `a[2] == 2, b[2] < 2, c[2] > 2` Since the remaining part is the same this doesn't allow any conclusion.

Comment: Indeed unless there can be duplicate values in the list, you'd be right in that it'd be trivial. Not sure until which point different implementations are able to handle non contiguous values, but I see what you mean with that ambiguity @a_guest

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, I think this should work for your print statement:

```
print("you searched for {} and we found it in the index number {} of the list".format(key, mid))
```

If you only want to print it when the index is the same as the value you can just add an if statement:

```
if key == mid:
    print("you searched for {} and we found it in the index number {} of the list".format(key, mid))
```

Does this answer your question?

Comment: I want to search the list without a key. I just want to find the elements that have the same value as the index number of their value. I could brute force it, but I want to use a binary search. The brute force would be a for loop with an if statement like if index == value, print value

Comment: @user2429456 Why do you want to use binary search? 1) It doesn't seem to be suited to your problem, and 2) it only works on sorted lists, but your data isn't sorted. And if it was, you'd need to allow duplicates in order to satisfy this condition for at least one element (except the trivial case where `alist = list(range(N))`). Can you please be more specific about your input data.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your problem correctly , you want to find the elements that have same value as their index number then you have to traverse the list and print the elements using condition
`print([i for i in alist if i==alist.index(i)])`